# How to calculate an average grade from mix of number grades and letter grades whose values are determined via lookup table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Data Table**

[image]

**Lookup Table**

[image]

I want to calculate the average grade score of each pupil using an array formula and without the use of helper columns. If all grade are numbers its simple enough to average those, but when letter grades are introduced into the mix I need to convert these to their number values using the lookup table and then average the whole row for each pupil.

So far I was able to take one row and convert all grades that are letters to their corresponding values using the formula below.

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("N"&(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(B2:E2),Table2[Grade],0)+1)))
```

which returns:

```
={#N/A,#N/A,7,3}
```

I then thought, great I got numbers in place of the letter grades, lets just "average" this result like so:

```
=AVERAGE(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("N"&(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(B2:E2),Table2[Grade],0)+1))))
```

which gives #N/A, which I do not understand when the following is completely allowed:

```
=AVERAGE({1,2,3})
```

Comment: If you have an error on a array element, `AVERAGE` will return that error as result

Comment: I tried removing errors using `IFNA()` but that messes up the whole array.

Comment: wrap items that can produce errors in iferror(function,0)

Comment: That does not work either unfortunately as shown below `=IFNA(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("N"&(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(B2:E2),Table2[Grade],0)+1))),"")` produces this array `={"","",#VALUE!,#VALUE!}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the case is to add all numerical grades to the 2 column **Grade** table you have in column M and N (technically it is not using helper columns?), then sort the `Grade` column in **ascending** order as shown below:

[image: Grade Table]

Then you can use the following **array formula** to find the average grade in cell `F2`:

```
=AVERAGE(LOOKUP(B2:E2,Tbl_Grade[Grade],Tbl_Grade[Attainment]))
```

Being an **array formula**, you **MUST** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar otherwise it will not function correctly. Then you can simply drag the formula down to apply across.

[image: Results]

> The logic is to use **LOOKUP** function to return the corresponding attainment for each given grade regardless if it is an actual number or a letter.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely an interesting solution, I never imagined LOOKUP can handle a whole range of values, I tried similar using index,matching but no luck, can you please elaborate how lookup can handle an array of values to search over?

Comment: @miro_x **LOOKUP** works in similar logic as **VLOOKUP** but it is able to return a range of values and it is defaulted to approximate match if there is no exact match. There are limitations for instance the look up range must be in ascending order otherwise it may return incorrect value. This function has 3 arguments, the first is the look up criteria, the second is the range where you will compare with first argument, and if you do not use the third argument, it will return the closest match result from the second range. Try google some working examples as this function is quite practical.

Answer (score 1):

Using VLOOKUPs seems like it would be much simpler:

`=AVERAGE(B2,C2,VLOOKUP(D2,$M$2:$N$7,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(E2,$M$2:$N$7,2,FALSE))`

Answer (score 0):

If you can tolerate changing "A*" to say "A+" (or something else that doesn't get interpreted as a wildcard) this may get you going:

```
=(SUM(B2:E2)+SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Table2[Grade],"="&B2:E2,Table2[Attainment])))/COUNTA(B2:E2)
```

The first `SUM` sums the numeric grades; the `SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(...))` sums the letter grades. Then divide the total by the number of grades (`COUNTA`).

Hope that helps

Comment: If I wanted to retain the "A*" notation, could I perhaps apply a substitute function to do "A*" to "A~*" within the formula?